# .htaccess RewriteCond

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This rule works just fine in a .htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /AccessDenied.html
ErrorDocument 404 /NotFound.html
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(index(\.(html|htm))?)$ / [R]
```

The same rule written as a conditional doesn't work:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /AccessDenied.html
ErrorDocument 404 /NotFound.html
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(index(\.(html|htm))?)$
RewriteRule ^(index(\.(html|htm))?)$ / [R]
```

I suppose my question is that why is the rule working in the first scenario, but not in the second? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Why do you want to use the version with the `RewriteCond`?

Comment: So, I can understand how the RewriteCond works; I haven't been able to get it to work at all; and I absolutely need it for other rules to be written later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your problem is that the `RewriteBase` processing (which always strips the leading slash) doesn't affect variables like `%{REQUEST_URI}` and doesn't apply for `RewriteCond` processing anyway.

So, the pattern `^(index(\.(html|htm))?)$` will work fine in a `RewriteRule`, but not a `RewriteCond` matching against the request URI. You need to include that leading slash (at least if you're using the beginning `^` anchor):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(index(\.(html|htm))?)$
```